# Excel VBA Folder Titles in Sequence

Tags: excel, vba, directory, sequence

I am really new to Excel VBA, and I'm trying to create a button to open a folder, with 2 subfolders, in a specified location. The difficulty I'm facing is that I want the main folders to be named in sequence (Counting up from AN0001, to AN0002 Etc), with it checking if the previous folder exists and automatically creating the next new one.

So far all I have is this:

```
Sub CREATE_FOLDER()

MkDir "\\mcbrishrfs01\Shared\Marketing\Business Insight\Costing\Cost Tracker\Email and PDF\AN0001"
MkDir "\\mcbrishrfs01\Shared\Marketing\Business Insight\Costing\Cost Tracker\Email and PDF\AN0001\Email"
MkDir "\\mcbrishrfs01\Shared\Marketing\Business Insight\Costing\Cost Tracker\Email and PDF\AN0001\PDF"

End Sub
```

Which will only make the AN0001 folder, provided it doesn't already exist, under the same name every time.

The subfolders would need to remain 'Email' and 'PDF' for each AN number.

Comment: What about combining your code with a `For..Next` loop? That way, you could increase the last folder name (`AN0001`,`AN0002`,`AN0003` and so on)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can change "36" in the loop depending on how many folders you want, this code gives you 35 folders with email and pdf inside each one:

```
 Sub CREATE_FOLDER()

 i = 1

 Do While i < 36

     MkDir "\\mcbrishrfs01\Shared\Marketing\Business Insight\Costing\Cost Tracker\Email and PDF\AN000" + Str(i)
     MkDir "\\mcbrishrfs01\Shared\Marketing\Business Insight\Costing\Cost Tracker\Email and PDF\AN000" + Str(i) + "\Email"
     MkDir "\\mcbrishrfs01\Shared\Marketing\Business Insight\Costing\Cost Tracker\Email and PDF\AN000" + Str(i) + "\PDF"

     i = i + 1

 Loop

 End Sub
```

Comment: As you might expect, this will create folders, named `AN0001`, `AN0002`, ..., but also `AN00010`, ..., `ÀN00036` (always three zeroes). C. Hacker, is this what you want or do you want `AN0010`, ..., `AN0036` (always a total of six characters)?

Comment: Just before you'd sent this I tried doing this:

`Sub CREATE_FOLDER()

For Each cell In Selection
   MkDir "O:\Marketing\Business Insight\Costing\Cost Tracker\Email and PDF\" & cell.Value
   MkDir "O:\Marketing\Business Insight\Costing\Cost Tracker\Email and PDF\" & cell.Value & "\Email"
   MkDir "O:\Marketing\Business Insight\Costing\Cost Tracker\Email and PDF\" & cell.Value & "\PDF"
Next cell

End Sub`

Which has worked. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Used the following:

`Sub MakeFolder()`

`For Each cell In Selection`
`MkDir "O:\Marketing\Business Insight\Costing\Cost Tracker\Email and PDF\" & cell.Value`
`MkDir "O:\Marketing\Business Insight\Costing\Cost Tracker\Email and PDF\" & cell.Value & "\Email"`
`MkDir "O:\Marketing\Business Insight\Costing\Cost Tracker\Email and PDF\" & cell.Value & "\PDF"`
`Next cell`

`End Sub`

As the file names were based on fields in the original document.